# Use Jython in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jython

I am trying to make use of jython inside a eclipse-plugin .. the plugin builds and starts good, however as soon as I use any python-stuff, the following happens:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-11-23 10:49:26.860
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/core/PyObject
    at cern.silecs.view.wizards.DesignClassWizard.performFinish(DesignClassWizard.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
............
```

I use maven to fetch my dependencies. Currently I have the following jython-entry in the pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have e.g. a java-file with the following code which build's well:

```
   ...
   import org.python.core.PyObject;
   ...
   PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get(funcName);
   ...
```

I even can CTRL+click on "PyObject" and see the source-code of the class. So for me it looks like the required dependencies are available, but during run-time they are not found.

Do I need to pass some environment-variables ? I already tried some, but they dont seem to make any difference.

Do I need to specify something special in "Bundle-ClassPath:" in the MANIFEST.MF ?

I already spend alot of time trying to get things fixed ... before I waste even more time I decided to ask for your help. I would be lucky on any hint!

Comment: Everything you use in an Eclipse plugin must be included in the plugin or in another plugin declared as a dependency. I don't know jython but someone may have packaged it up in a plugin already, otherwise you will have to included everything in your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have already installed "pydev", which seems to be the right plugin. So  I added  "org.python.pydev.jython" and all other pyton related plugins into the "List of required plugins". That added some lines to "Require-Bundle" in MANIFEST.MF. However it did not help on the "NoClassDefFoundError".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I got the problem solved. It seems like eclipse does not fully integrate the jar-files, downloaded by maven automatically.

1.) In the tab "runtime" there is a frame "Classpath". There I needed to add a the jython-standalone jar-file, which was downloaded by maven.

2.) Right click on the Project--> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries and add the jython-standalone jar-file.